# Window does not react to raised property changed events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have had an issue with my View Model that acts... wierd. I have some properties which i call RaisePropertyChanged(() => TotalHours) on, but on the view side nothing happens. Here is a rundown on my Model. I run MVVM Light.

My model which is called AxData in my viewmodel consists of two ObservableCollections which holds some objects which both implements ObservableObject. These react fine in the view. I also have in my model a IsDirty and TotalHours property. These does not react at all. The Axdata is implementing the Observableobject from MVVM Light.

To be able to use my IsDirty flag I subscribe to the two collection with CollectionChanged. I also subscribe to the PropertyChanged event on the object inside these collection by doing the following:

```
private void AttachListners()
{
    WorkUnits.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    Projects.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object o, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
{
    if (notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (ObservableObject item in notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += OnSubItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    if (notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (ObservableObject item in notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs?.OldItems)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= OnSubItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    IsDirty = true;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => TotalHours);
}

private void OnSubItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    IsDirty = true;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => TotalHours);
}
```

When I debug the code i can perfectly reach the RaisePropertyChanged(() => TotalHours) in both OnCollectionChanged and OnSubItemPropertyChanged. So I do raise the flag on TotalHours. IsDirty raises by itself:

```
public bool IsDirty
{
    set
    {
        _isDirty = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsDirty);
    }
    get { return _isDirty; }
}
```

Total hours implementation

```
public double TotalHours
{
    get { return WorkUnits.Sum(unit => unit.Hours); }
}
```

TotalHours is just binded to a textblock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AxData.TotalHours}"/>
```

IsDirty is used by my view model where is subscribes to my models property changed event:

```
private void AxDataOnPropertyChanged(object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    if (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName == "IsDirty")
    {
        PopulateTitle();
    }
}
```

I should note that all object in my ObservableCollections are mostly edited through Datagrids. All changes are executed correctly and all data changed correctly, but I don't know if that information could be vital.

So why does my View not react to changes? Hope you can help because I have been stuck on this for about a month now. What am I missing.

Comment: What is AxData? Do you raise the PropertyChanged event for this object? And how is your TotalHours property implemented?

Comment: "ObservableCollections which holds some objects" <- Do your objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: You may also want to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding

Comment: I edited my post in response to all you comments. I'm sorry I missed a few key points. Axdata is the name of my model and it implements ObservableObject from MVVM light. I added total hours implementation to the post. All objects in my ObservableCollections also implement ObservableObject. I tried using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to my binding but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are struggling to apply item changes in an ObservableCollection. This is common issue in WPF and I recommend you to use `ObservableCollectionEx` library. It helps to bubble up `PropertyChanges` of items inside of `ObservableCollection`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObservableCollectionEx/

Several `ObservableCollectionEx` libraries are found in nuget and they are implemented almost same manner.